# Pasar datos de un objeto a otro con diferente estructura

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy  buscando la manera en javascript de pasar los datos de un objeto de un tipo a otro de diferente tipo.

El primer objeto seria este

```
   (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
date: "2018-03-29T13:34:00.000+0200"
location:
    locationx: "Almacen"
    id: 21
__proto__: Object
id: 7
__proto__: Object
```

Ahora quiero pasar los datos de locationx y date a otro objeto con esta estructura.

```
 pr: EventInput[] = [
    {
      title: '',  // Aquí seria locationx
      start: '',     // Aquí seria date
    },  
    {
      title: '',
      start: '',
    },
  ];
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que pueden ser cientos de datos , ¿alguna idea? gracias

EDITO

En FullCalendar tengo que obtener los eventos iniciales desde una petición http.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private vacationService: VacationService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadEvents();
  }

 pr: EventInput[] = [
    {
      title: 'All-day event',
      start: '2021-05-16',
    },
    {
      title: 'All-day event',
      start: '2021-05-18',
    },
  ];

  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    headerToolbar: { 
      left: '',
      center: 'title',
    },
    editable: true, 
    initialEvents: this.pr,  
  
  };

  loadEvents(): void {
      this.vacationService.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
        // My data
        console.log(data);
      })
  }
}
```

La variable pr contiene los eventos iniciales que puedo hacer manualmente pero necesito que sean de los datos de mi petición a la bd. Es decir necesito pasar el data a la variable pr teniendo en cuenta de que tienen diferente estructura.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema?

Comment: ambos serían arreglo de objetos ?

Comment: Sí , son lo que puse en la pregunta.

Comment: @DavidRod podrias poner lo que has intentado? Porque el tipo de preguntas "Tengo que hacer esto", no son bien recibidas sin mostrar lo trabajado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion `Array.map` para ese proposito.

Suponiendo que el array inicial está almacenado en `data`:

```
const newArray = data.map(o => ({ title: o.location.locationx, start: o.date}))
```